# Kleinian Groups and 3-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, quotient-spaces

I was reading a paper on hyperbolic geometry and was unable to understand the following

> Gluing opposite faces of the dodecahedron by a three-fifths twist we
>   obtain a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold called the Seifert-Weber
>   dodecahedral space. The group of face-pairing transformations generate
>   a Kleinian group such that the quotient of hyperbolic 3-space by this
>   group is the Seifert-Weber dodecahedral space.

I am unable to produce a proof of this. Some help or even a sketch of the proof would be appreciated. Also, can somebody suggest a good reference for things of this kind.

Comment: The Poincare Polyhedron Theorem will do this pretty easily. If you don't that theorem, it's covered in Ratcliffe's book "Foundations of hyperbolic geometry".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will look that up